# base64 decoded image from captureVisibleTab. How to save it via GD library to jpg ot png?

Tags: php, gd

I have this code which send an image to test.php:

```
 chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
   chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab(null, function(img) {

   $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "http://imap24.pl/tests/dom/testy/test.php",
   data: "img=" + img,
   success: function(e){
     alert(e);
   }});


   });
 });
```

The img is base64 (data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZ...). I have this script in test.php

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['img'])) {
$img = $_POST['img'];
$data = base64_decode($img);
$im = imagecreatefromstring($data);
imagejpeg($im, 'simpletext.jpg');
imagedestroy($im);
}
?>
```

And as the result I get this message

> the data is not in a recognised format

What's wrong?

Comment: Where do you get this message, in which line? Are you 100% sure your image data is base64 encoded?

Comment: I think taht Yes it's base64 encoded, when I debug first js code the img variable contains data:image/jpeg;base64....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you stated the image looks like this: `data:image/jpeg;base64,…`
So you should strip the first part of this Data-URL, then write it directly to a file:

```
$comma = strpos($img, ',');
$data = base64_decode(substr($img, $comma+1));
file_put_contents("simpletext.jpg", $data);
```

Comment: You don't need to involve GD at all -- I've amended your snippet to remove the unnecessary `imagecreatefromstring`/`imagejpeg` round-trip.

Comment: @duskwuff, you cannot be sure, that the given content is REALLY an image. That should be at leat rudimentary validated.

Comment: TimWolla, duskwuff i got an error when I try to open an image simpletext.jpg :/

Comment: And it's some problem while sending img from js to php, because when I copy the img content from js and put it in php like variable everything is ok.

Comment: Then you should check your input with var_dump or similar commands.